# Drupal 7 Age Gateway

Tags: 7

I have a website that will need an age gateway because it contains content about alcohol.  I'm looking for an easy way to do this, without needing to create a custom module because I haven't done any and the deadline is looming.

It would need to redirect to a page gathering age information, and only allow access to the site if >= 21 years old.  Specific pages would be exempt.

If anyone knows a module that takes care of this, or has any ideas I'm open to suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Please try module [Terms of Use](http://drupal.org/project/terms_of_use) . It won't check user age directly but the user has to sign understanding your website terms of service before registration.

Answer (score 0):

I grabbed a module from the [OpenBrewery](https://www.drupal.org/project/openbrewery) theme and tweaked it to be a yes or no form. Pretty easy.

Comment: Any idea which module? I just downloaded openbrewery and it doesn't appear to have any modules